# Are questions related to superstition considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As we know, Hinduism dharma is filled with superstition and beliefs of people, so should we consider them on topic?

To clarify my point, I will post few examples like —

- Does using salt prevents evil eye and black magic?
- Does using lime and chilly help to ward off evil eyes
- Should we prevent getting an hair cut on Saturday, Monday and Tuesday?

---

Links to refer on Hinduism Superstition

- [List of Superstition in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_superstitions_in_India)
- [Famous Indian Superstition](http://listdose.com/famous-indian-superstitions/)

Thanks to [@Aditya Somani](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16288993#16288993) for sharing them

Comment: I believe that every superstition has a story behind it. if the question is like "why we people believe *?" then it should be on-topic. because it has a story behind it.

Comment: @Mr_Green Please read the answer and mostly, the last point highlighted in bold :)

Comment: yeah I am sure there is a story behind it. but don't know that story. :)

Answer (score 6):

According to me, we should consider Superstition topics as **off topic** on this website.

**BUT**

Here's a catch, I will write the same question in two ways which makes a huge difference, for example

- Does using lime and chilly help to ward off evil eyes

**Compared to**

- Why people use lime and chilly and hang them up on their home entrances and on their vehicles etc?

Here, both questions are different, I would consider type 1 as off topic because it will attract opinion based answers. Some people do believe in these superstitions whereas others don't, compared to point 2, where the user asks the reason to do so, which is on topic, I would like to emphasize again to refer the comparison and make sure you don't get confused with the scenario.

**It is off topic to ask whether a person believes in a superstition but it is on topic to know the reason behind doing so**

Comment: +1 for the example showcasing the difference between what could be off-topic and what could be on-topic. As you mentioned, opinion based answers should be avoided in this case as well.

Comment: +1 yeah I was trying to say the same in above comment :)